# Captured group in optional part of a regular expression

Tags: c#, regex, regex-group

I want to capture a group in an optional part of a string.

For example:

In the string **"firstName:Bill-lastName:Gates"**, I want to capture 2 groups :

1. Bill
2. Gates

I use this regex:

```
firstName:(.*)-lastName:(.*)
```

But when the lastName-part is optional, I still want to capture the first
group (firstName).

I used this regex, to make the lastName-part optional (in a non-capturing group):

```
firstName:(.*)(?:-lastName:(.*))?
```

Using this updated regex, the resulting groups are:

- when the lastName part is not present, for example **"firstName:Bill"** the captured groups are:

  1. Bill
  2. /empty string/

which is *correct*,

- when the firstName and lastName parts are present: **"firstName:Bill-lastName:Gates"**, the *groups are not correct*:

  1. Bill-lastName:Gates
  2. /empty/

I think it has to do with greediness of the first capturing group, but how to adjust this regex to make the regex work when the lastName-part is optional?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right, it is about greediness. Find a delimiter for the first match group. So, if your firstname "never" contains the dash, only match everything but the dash with the first match group.

```
firstName:([^-]*)(?:-lastName:(.*))?

firstName:([^-]*)(?:-lastName:(.*))?
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/itz8L16qdZ66HCM3)

If you cannot find such a delimiter you would need to take a different approach. Even if you try to make the first pattern "lazy", the Regex engine always prefers a *bigger* match over matching an additional optional match.

This is, because *lazy* matchgroups will *match the first string that satisfies the expression* (! important wording !)

There might be an option with look arrounds, but you could also use a or -statement without providing optional matches:

```
firstName:(.*)-lastName:(.*)|firstName:(.*)
```

This way, the regex engine would match either or, but prefer the pattern with 2 matches since it is listed first. Only if that does not apply, it will try the single match.

Comment: Thanks, works great! +1 for the Debuggex visualizer and the or-statement explanation.

Comment: Why are you repeating the same line twice?

Answer (score 2):

Even though you accepted @dognose's answer already, I assure you there are first names with a dash in them (You don't wanna piss off Jean-Claude van Damme). I would advise you to do it like so:

```
    firstName:((?:(?!-lastName:).)*)(?:-lastName:(.*))?
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/sH3tiYGVqh7BncDf)

You can see from the visualization that the `(?:(?!-lastName:).)` says *"if the current position is not followed by '**-lastName:**', capture another character"*